# Remove unverified emails from google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, google-sheets-formula, match

so I have a spreadsheet with name, email and phone number now I'm using another service to verify those emails but the problem is that the software is returning valid emails and now I wanna remove the rows which don't have valid emails how can I achieve that. As the email verifier is only giving me valid emails and I want to remove the rows which don't have valid emails.

Here's an explainer video on what's the issue I'm facing. https://www.loom.com/share/33c1a5b271044b32816060163f86c162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a few steps, yes.

- let's say your data is on Sheet1
- paste your verified emails in Sheet2 column A
- create Sheet3 and use this formula:

---

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:Z, COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A, Sheet1!F:F))
```

[image]

- next, select all the data on Sheet3
- press <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>
- and right after that press <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + V</kbd>

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12c0dfN9N3FqI1B5HKAcoLdxsWfcd6eL1F61bVUA-LkU/edit#gid=1050189018)